# How to sort a converted field using string_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

How do I sort a converted field. There are similar questions, however I dont know why its not working by me

-- the field 'number' is an integer

```
string_agg(distinct cast(number as varchar(4)) , ', ')
```

however the results return in very strange random order

```
Results
12,11,10,1,29
```

I simply wanted it sorted normally 1,10,11,12,29

I tried this code based on the available posts but it didnt work and received the following error

```
string_agg(
    distinct cast(number as varchar(4)),', ' order by number) 
    as SPJ

--ERROR: in an aggregate with distinct order by expressions must appear in argument list
```

So tried this too and not the answer I want

```
string_agg(
    distinct cast(number as varchar(4)) , ', ' order by
                            cast(number as varchar(4))) as SPJ
results 
10,11,8,9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all complicated because of the types -- strings are not ordered the same way as numbers.  So, you can do this using arrays instead:

```
with t as (
      select num
      from (values (1), (10), (11), (12), (29), (2)) v(num)
     )
select array_to_string(array_agg(distinct num order by num), ', ')
from t ;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Of course it will, but not with the `distinct` (which I had left out).  Your version with `distinct` returns "42P10: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list".